# MVC Intermediate page between redirecting to another long load time page

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

How using MVC C# (without the use of JS or JQuery) can I send a user to `/home/stasis` which will load with a loader image (already implemented using css), and then send them to the final url (which has a really long load time, and users end up clicking multiple times - not helping themselves)

The problem is that the use of JS and JQuery won't work, as this needs to work as an in-app webview as well (which doesn't support either JS or JQuery). So I go to `/home/index` click on a link to take me to `/home/stasis` which will load, then automatically begin loading the final url lets say google.com for example.

Comment: after a second thought. I do have an ugly hack that might work. First the server would return the div tag for the loading screen, and without closing the connection do the loading on server side. Once its done return the new page's html along with the style to hide the loadng div

Comment: why wouldn't javascript work for this? Seems like a good use case for SignalR and EventHandlers

Comment: @Eonasdan probably his page is hosted inside another container with js disabled

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Without javascript, we have to hope that the browser and server will do the right thing:

1. The browser will display the entity content when the server returns a 307 redirect.
2. The server will not return partial entity while the long-running request is pending.  In other words.  The long-running request should return all its entity data in the final second the request.
3. The browser won't clear the screen until the first bytes of the next entity have arrived.

Assuming the browser and server behave like this, MVC doesn't offer an easy way to do it.  You need to:

1. Create a new class derived from ActionResult.
2. In your ActionResult's ExecuteResult() method, write output to ControllerContext.HttpContext.Response.  Set the response code to 307, set the RedirectLocation, and write whatever content you want to display to the OutputStream.